# Observations in Group Per Any Rolling 5 Minute Period (Snowflake SQL)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 2 columns, here is a sample:

| ID | DateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 13:19:15 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 13:20:19 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 15:01:37 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 10:08:21 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 12:09:32 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 15:07:25 |

I am trying to build a SQL query in Snowflake that returns all of the IDs that have a minimum of 2 or more records within **ANY** rolling 5 minute window. For the example data provided, ID 1 would be returned but ID 2 would not since all times for that ID are more than 5 minutes apart.

When attempting to find solutions to this problem, it seems that a recursive CTE may be the correct approach to solve this, but I can't seem to understand exactly how to approach this.

Any support or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTE for data -

```
with data_cte (id, date1) as
(
select * from values
(1,'2022-04-01 13:19:15'::timestamp),
(1,'2022-04-01 13:20:19'::timestamp),
(1,'2022-04-01 15:01:37'::timestamp),
(2,'2022-04-01 10:08:21'::timestamp),
(2,'2022-04-01 12:09:32'::timestamp),
(2,'2022-04-01 15:07:25'::timestamp)
), twindow_cte as (
select
id,
nvl(
TIMESTAMPDIFF('minute',date1,
lead(date1) over (partition by id order by null)), 0) tdiff from
data_cte)
select distinct id from twindow_cte a where
1< (select count(*) from twindow_cte b
where b.tdiff <=5 and b.id = a.id);
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |